# How can I resolve from System.Type without referencing the container

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I want to be able to create an instance of a component from the windsor container for the type described by a System.Type instance.

I realise I can do something like:

```
public object Create(Type type)
{
    return globalContainer.Resolve(type);
}
```

But I want to be able to do this without refering to the container. I was wondering whether this could be done using the typed factory facility? Something like

```
public interface IObjFactory
{
    object Create(Type type);
}

public class Installer: IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        container.Register(Component.For<IObjFactory>().AsFactory());
    }
}

public class Something
{
    private readonly IObjFactory objFactory;

    public Something(IObjFactory objFactory)
    {
        this.objFactory = objFactory;
    }

    public void Execute(Type type)
    {
        var instance = objFactory.Create(type);

        // do stuff with instance
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not give the method a type parameter and return that type, rather than object?

Comment: Magnus - I am dealing with a 3rd party API and all they pass me is a System.Type for resolution.

Comment: RochardNoogle - I think as long as you've already passed the container in to create the class with the create method, your first example is fine. It's simple, and doesn't seem difficult to replace in the future if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below shows how you can do this with Windsor. I would however recommend against making such a generic factory. It is probably better to only allow creation of components implementing a specific interface.

Kind regards,
Marwijn.

```
public interface IObjFactory
{
    object Create(Type type);
}

public class FactoryCreatedComponent
{

}

public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        container.Register(
            Component.For<FactoryCreatedComponent>(),
            Component.For<IObjFactory>().AsFactory(new TypeBasedCompenentSelector()));
    }
}

public class TypeBasedCompenentSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    protected override Type GetComponentType(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        return (Type) arguments[0];
    }
}



class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(new Installer());
        var factory = container.Resolve<IObjFactory>();

        var component = factory.Create(typeof (FactoryCreatedComponent));

        Debug.Assert(typeof(FactoryCreatedComponent) == component.GetType());
    }
}
```